# ui-router nested state is not resolving

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

Here i tried to resolve a nested state of ui-router to the same ui-view element which parent state is also using.
Since the hooks shows that state got resolved but component/template is not resolved.

Nested states:

```
{ 
  name: 'people', 
  url: '/people', 
  component: 'people',
  resolve: {
    people: function(PeopleService) {
      return PeopleService.getAllPeople();
    }
  }
},

{ 
  name: 'people.person', 
  url: '/people/{personId}', 
  component: 'person',
  resolve: {
    person: function(PeopleService, $transition$) {
      return PeopleService.getPerson($transition$.params().personId);
    }
  }
}
```

Both 'people' and 'people.person' were tried to resolve to the same ui-view element

Is there any way to load the template of child state to the same ui-view element?
Please guide me to the proper implementation.

[PLUNKER](https://plnkr.co/edit/W8PDCmOFV34wSXcpL6xk?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding/experience with the ui-view and nested resources you have two options:

1) Take them out of being nested (although probably not the best) you can simulate nesting using approrpriate configuration.  Here is an example
of this type: https://plnkr.co/edit/8MtCk0rPRy4CaEjsPDe8?p=preview

The main changes are:

a) Removing the nesting:

```
name: 'people.person',
```

becomes

```
name: 'person',
```

b) Removing the nesting from the template:

```
'<a ui-sref="people.person({ personId: person.id })">' +
```

becomes

```
'<a ui-sref="person({ personId: person.id })">' +
```

2) Using named views, you can force the people.person into the same named ui-view using the following:

https://plnkr.co/edit/qWS7SjJ9PNytQFjZRDr3?p=preview

a) Changing all the component: 'componentName' to

```
views: {'!content': 'componentName'}
```